# Emit deprecation warnings with Apollo client

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client

## Background

We are working on a fairly large [Apollo](https://www.apollographql.com/) project. A very simplified version of our api looks like this:

```apollo
type Operation {
    foo: String
    activity: Activity
}

type Activity {
    bar: String
    # Lots of fields here ...
}
```

We've realised splitting `Operation` and `Activity` does no benefit and adds complexity. We'd like to merge them. But there's a lot of queries that assume this structure in the code base. In order to make the transition gradual we add `@deprecated` directives:

```apollo
type Operation {
    foo: String
    bar: String
    activity: Activity @deprecated
}

type Activity {
    bar: String @deprecated(reason: "Use Operation.bar instead")
    # Lots of fields here ...
}
```

## Actual question

Is there some way to highlight those deprecations going forward? Preferably by printing a warning in the browser console when (in the test environment) running a query that uses a deprecated field?

Comment: I'm thinking that it can be done in a [apollo-client](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client) middleware?

Comment: I'm also interested in some kind of implementation or tool that does this :)

Comment: @Striped Added solution below.

Comment: [Someone built a plugin](https://github.com/alexxiyang/apollo-deprecated-highlight)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GraphQL [schema directives](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/directives/) [can be customized](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/schema-directives/). So below is a solution that prints a warning on the server (**Edit 2023:** [And here's a plugin that propagates the warning to the client](https://github.com/alexxiyang/apollo-deprecated-highlight)):

```js
import { SchemaDirectiveVisitor } from "graphql-tools"
import { defaultFieldResolver } from "graphql"
import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server"


class DeprecatedDirective extends SchemaDirectiveVisitor {
  public visitFieldDefinition(field ) {
    field.isDeprecated = true
    field.deprecationReason = this.args.reason

    const { resolve = defaultFieldResolver, } = field
    field.resolve = async function (...args) {
      const [_,__,___,info,] = args
      const { operation, } = info
      const queryName = operation.name.value
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.warn(
      `Deprecation Warning:
        Query [${queryName}] used field [${field.name}]
        Deprecation reason: [${field.deprecationReason}]`)
      return resolve.apply(this, args)
    }
  }

  public visitEnumValue(value) {
    value.isDeprecated = true
    value.deprecationReason = this.args.reason
  }
}

new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  schemaDirectives: {
    deprecated: DeprecatedDirective,
  },
}).listen().then(({ url, }) => {
  console.log(`  Server ready at ${url}`)
})
```